# decoding speed in Data.Text

Tags: haskell, text, character-encoding

In Haskell's `Data.Text.Encoding`, presuming one presents a pure ASCII `ByteString`, is decodeLatin1 very much faster than decodeUtf8? Intuitively It seems like there would be at least one more machine instruction given the nature of utf-8 (ie a test of the top bit).  I know I could do my own profiling, but I presume this may have been done already so that is why I ask.

Comment: Are you really willing to travel back forty years in text technology time just to save a few machine instructions?

Comment: I am just curious about it.

Comment: What UTF-8 decoders often do is that they use a bitmask to check that the next e.g. 8 bytes don't have the leading bit set.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the underlying C code that the text library uses internally for the decoder. Specifically the function `_hs_text_decode_latin1`:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.0.0.1/src/cbits/cbits.c

> is decodeLatin1 very much faster than decodeUtf8

The answer to this is simply that it shouldn't matter, you should choose to use latin1 decoder if you need to work with existing latin1 text data. Anything else is just microoptimization for almost all cases, the `text` library is already very heavily optimized.